# python exception handing error RequestException

Tags: python, api

i am trying a try catch method in a python application. i not sure what mistake i made in whether it is a indentation issue or something

this is my code.

```
try:
            ivurl = f'{api}/company/{id}/contacts?'
            payload: Dict[str, Union[bool, int]] = {'id': True}
            response = get_iv_response(url=ivurl, payload=payload)
            email_contact_totalresult: int = response.get('totalResults')
            email = int(email_contact_totalresult)
            payload: Dict[str, Union[bool, int]] = {'name': True}
            response = get_iv_response(url=ivurl, payload=payload)
            phone_contact_totalresult: int = response.get('totalResults')
            phone = int(phone_contact_totalresult)
            print ("here")
            if email > 0 or phone > 0:
                print (f"{id} has contacts")
                update_query = f"""update section 
                                set has_contact = true ,
                                updated = '{cur_date}'      
                            where name = '{id}'
                            """
                print(update_query)
                insert_query = f"""insert into quota(name,age)
                                values ('{name}',
                                        '{age}')"""
                print (insert_query)
                cursor.execute(update_query)
                cursor.execute(insert_query)
            
                conn.commit()
            else :
                print (f"{id} doesnot  has contacts")

        except:requests.RequestException as error1:
            print ("error1:",error1)
        # except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as error2:
        #     print ("error1:",error2)
        # except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as error3:
        #     print ("error3:",error3)
        # except requests.exceptions.Timeout as error4:
        #     print ("error4:",error4)

    print ("job done")
    print(end_time)
    print('Duration: {}'.format(end_time - start_time))
```

i am getting error near the "as" invalid syntax

picture error of this issue : https://ibb.co/Wn5pnM3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax should be something like this:

```
try:
    #this expression was not defined anywhere, hence the NameError
    print(leromipsum) 
except NameError as error1:
    print("meh")
```

So in your code, I think you should remove the identation before:

```
except:requests.RequestException as error1:
    print ("error1:",error1)
```

and remove the colon after except:

```
except requests.RequestException as error1:
    print ("error1:",error1)
```

Cheers

Edit:

```
try:
    print("this code runs")
    raise requests.HTTPError
    print("this code is skipped, if an error occurs")
except requests.RequestException as error1:
    print ("error1:",error1)
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as error2:
    print ("error1:",error2)
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as error3:
    print ("error3:",error3)
except requests.exceptions.Timeout as error4:
    print ("error4:",error4)
```

This minimal example works for me.

Comment: thanks mate , but when i am adding multiple except statement i am getting this error "Bad except clauses order (RequestException is an ancestor class of HTTPError)" for all 3 except functions

Comment: I can't really help, without knowing, what you are working with here. And working code, that produces the error would be really helpful. I think it could be enough to put the first except that catches error 1 after error4. Also, are you planing to use the RequestException different from HTTPError? If not, why catch them independently, when one an ancestor of the other?

Comment: and please fix your indentation, as this makes it even harder to tell, where your problem lies.